# Problem with compiling n-body simulation with CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a linux ubuntu 10.04 LTS freshly installed on my x64 PC, and I just followed [this step-by-step installation guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625433) to install NVidia CUDA on my PC. But when I `cd` into `~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/src/nbody` and try to make the nbody simulation, it just prints out:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../bin/linux/release/nbody] Error 1
```

Is this a solvable problem?
I'm a newbie in Linux (and in Cuda programming) so please help me understanding.

Comment: Do you have OpenGL development libraries installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Synaptic Package Manager and install the packages with libgl, libglu, libglut, etc. For example, libgl1-mesa and all its dev variants, freeglut, etc.

sudo apt-get install build-essential x-window-system-dev
will also get you the vast majority of those.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Accept to let others know the question has been addressed.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /usr/lib/

ls -la | grep libGL.so
```

if libGL.so exists

```
sudo rm libGL.so
```

then run

```
sudo ln -s libGL.so.270.41.19 libGL.so
```

or whatever version of libGL.so you have